# sbs 2011 my docs redirection not working

Tags: group-policy, windows-sbs-2011, folder-redirection

I'm in the process of migrating from SBS 2003 to SBS 2011 and am having trouble with My Documents redirection GPO.  When I do a gpresult it indicates that the GP is processing successfully. If I go into C:\users\thiername\ I can look at their desktop or music folder and the path is \sbs2011\RedirectedFolders\username however the Documents folder is still C:\users\thiername\documents.  I can confirm that the user has full privileges to their folder on the sbs server.

Please help asap, and as always thank you for any responses.

msindle

Comment: The default redirection setting for the Music folder is to follow the Documents folder so presumably the Documents folder is being redirected but that doesn't mean that it hasn't been changed from the default, which begs the question: Have you verified that the Documents folders is being redirected in the relevant GPO?

Comment: By doing a gpresult it tells me that it is getting its group policies from the 2011 server and further down it says that the Documents Redirection police was applied.  Unless there is another way for me to check I believe everything is being applied properly its just not redirecting the documents folder.

Comment: The Documents Redirection policy may be getting applied but are the redirection settings in that GPO set correctly? You can check on the Settings tab in GPRESULTS or you can check the GPO directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After backing away from the problem for a few minutes I finally found the answer to what was going on...As it turns out if you stop sharing the User Folders from the source server prior to the user logging into their system it does not redirect their My Docs over to the destination server.  Sounds simple enough when you say it out loud, however it makes me a little nervous that Monday morning I may have a user that is still working in their My Docs folder from the source server that is about to be turned off in a week or two.